# Running a function every second and compare with a value a second before.

Tags: python

I have to run the code every second and compare if the return values are equal or not for the current execution and a second before. I tried threading but i couldn't find a way to store the values to compare.

```
import numpy as np
import random 

def ran ():
    a = random.randint(1,101)
    return a
```

Comment: What about `time.sleep(1)`?

Comment: It just runs it every second , I need to be able to compare if the random numbers from execution in previous second is the same or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
import random
import time


def ran():
    a = random.randint(1, 101)
    return a


previous_rand = None
while True:
    new_rand = ran()
    if previous_rand and previous_rand == new_rand:
        print 'Equal!'
    else:
        print 'Not equal!'
    previous_rand = new_rand
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

ok i wrote some similar code a few years ago i hope it helps

```
import numpy as np
import random
import time


def ran ():
    a = random.randint(1,101)
    print(a)
    return a


def chk(a,b):
    if a==b:
        return True
    else:
        return False

while True:
    x=ran()
    time.sleep(1)
    x3=ran()
    s=chk(x,x3)
    if s==True:
        print("Both numbers are same")
    else:
        print("Not Equall")
```

Comment: This works as well , however i need my code to be leaner so i accepted sobek answer. Thank you for your answer .